# How to check if the value of one obj exists in the another obj?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I wanna make follow/unfollow toggle button, and following / follower list(object in array) will be called seperately from server.
Follower list needs to have both unfollow/follow button status.
When I call follower list, how can I check the IDs of the people who follow me matches the IDs of my following list & reflect in on the button?

example following, follower object in array

```
[{id: 1, profileImg: xxx},{id: 2, profileImg: xxx},{id: 3, profileImg: xxx}... ]
```

my code in js below

```
const {  select } = props;
    const [choice, setChoice] = useState(select);
    const [followingList, setFollowingList] = useState([]);
    const [followerList, setFollowerList] = useState([]);
    

    const handleChoice = (e) => {
        setChoice(e.target.value);
    };
    

    useEffect(() => {
        getFollowing()
            .then((res) => {
                setFollowingList(res);
            })
            .then(
                getFollower().then((res) => {
                    setFollowerList(res);
                }),
            );
    }, []);
```

my code in html

```
<Container onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
    <TogglebtnContainer>
         <ToggleBtn onClick={handleChoice} value="following" choice{choice}>Following</ToggleBtn>
         <ToggleBtn onClick={handleChoice} value="follower" choice={choice}>Follower</ToggleBtn>
    </TogglebtnContainer>
        <FollowContainer>
          <Follow>
        {choice === 'following'? (followingList.map((follow, idx) => {
        return (
                        <div className="follow-item" key={idx}>
            <div className="follow-img"><img src={follow.profileImg} alt="UserPic" />             </div>
            <div className="follow-name">{follow.nickname}</div>
                <FollowBtn key={follow.id}>Unfollow</FollowBtn></div>
                                            );})
        : (followerList.map((follow, idx) => {
            return (
                <div className="follow-item" key={idx}>
                <div className="follow-img">
                <img src={follow.profileImg} alt="UserPic" />
                </div>
                <div className="follow-name">{follow.nickname}</div>
                <FollowBtn key={follow.id}>follow</FollowBtn>
                </div>
                                               })}
      </Follow>
      </FollowContainer>
      </Container>
```

I thought I could check if this IDs matches IDs of my following list and create a new boolean state.
(ex [isFollowing, setIsFollowing = useState(false)) but couldn't find a way.

```
getFollower().then((res) => {
    setFollowerList(res);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know which followers the user is already following and follow/unfollow followers

```
  short answer, set a flag when loading the data

  useEffect(() => {

      let isValidScope = true;
         
      const fetchData = async () => {

         const followingList =  await getFollowing();
         if (!isValidScope) { return; }

         setFollowingList(followingList);

         let followersList = await getFollower();
         if (!isValidScope) { return; }

         const followingUserIds = followingList?.map(f => f.id)

         followersList = followersList?.map(follower => {
             return followingUserIds?.includes(follower.id) ? 
                     { ...follower, isFollowing: true } : follower
         }

         setFollowerList(followersList)

      }

      fetchData()

      return () => { isValidScope = false }

    }, []);

    const onFollowFollower = (followerId) => {
         const followersList = followerList?.map(follower => {
             return follower.id === followerId ? 
                     { ...follower, isFollowing: true } : follower
         }
         setFollowerList(followersList)
    }

    const onUnfollowFollower = (followerId) => {
        const followersList = followerList?.map(follower => {
             return follower.id === followerId ? 
                     { ...follower, isFollowing: false } : follower
         }
         setFollowerList(followersList)
    }
```

Render code

```
<Follow>
        {choice === 'following'? (followingList.map((follow, idx) => {
              return (
                 <div className="follow-item" key={idx}>
                     <div className="follow-img"><img src={follow.profileImg} alt="UserPic" />             </div>
                      <div className="follow-name">{follow.nickname}</div>
                      <FollowBtn key={follow.id}>Unfollow</FollowBtn>
                  </div>
               );})
               : (followerList.map((follow, idx) => {
                     return (
                       <div className="follow-item" key={idx}>
                          <div className="follow-img">
                            <img src={follow.profileImg} alt="UserPic" />
                           </div>
                           <div className="follow-name">{follow.nickname}</div>
                              
                              { follow?.isFollowing ? <FollowBtn () => onUnfollowFollower(follow.id)>Unfollow</FollowBtn> : null }
                               { !follow?.isFollowing ? <FollowBtn onClick={() => onFollowFollower(follow.id)>Follow</FollowBtn> : null }
                       </div>
          })}
    </Follow>
```

You can read about [working with list](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state) in the new React docs

if you are refetching the follower and following list on every change it will be better to recalculate the followers list using a useMemo on every change

Hope this helps you in someway

Comment: The problem has been resolved. I need to study the solution and document you suggested. It's very helpful. Thank you so much!